# Debugging PHP Output

Tags: php, debugging

I have a php website that on certain pages is adding a dot or space before the first html tag. I can't figure out where it is coming from - is there a way to debug the code so i can see where it is coming from?
Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Could you provide some code of a problematic page?

Comment: Or could you provide a link to a URL

Comment: Firebug web developer extension might help

Answer (score 2):

To help prevents this happening it is considered a good practice to don't end your PHP file with a `?>`.

You possibly have some file that are this way (notice the extra space after the `?>`):

```
<?php
    // Some code //
?>
```

If you would remove the `?>` at the end, the extra space at the end of the file won't be interpreted as something to output.

> For files that contain only PHP code,
>   the closing tag ("?>") is never
>   permitted. It is not required by PHP,
>   and omitting it´ prevents the
>   accidental injection of trailing white
>   space into the response.

Source: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html

Comment: -1 **Awful, horrible** advise. Under no circumstance should you ever not include the ending `?>`. EVER.

Comment: @Michael - Why? This doesn't really qualify as an explanation to justify your downvote!

Comment: @Michael Why do you say this?  I don't know if I necessarily agree with that.  In fact I think the Zend coding standard says to leave it out on files that only contain php code.

Comment: @Michael Actually, you're completely wrong. [You shouldn't include the closing `?>`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html) in files that contain **only PHP** code, according to PHP's own developers. CodeIgniter and Drupal agree, and so do many other developers.

Comment: @Micheal Even the Zend Framework is for the practice of not including the end PHP tag for file that contains only PHP. See my edit.

Comment: Good practice is to write good, clean, semantically correct code. You wouldn't write an HTML document without the `</html>`. Leaving off the closing `?>` is lazy. It promotes lazy code writing. If the problem is white space at the end, fix the problem; Don't remove your closing tag to hack around it.

Comment: @Michael Irigoyen: Omitting the closing `?>` is generally considered good practice, and it encouraged by a lot of coding standards. Including it makes you more prone to error. Omitting it is not being lazy, it's being smart. See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: @mfonda Not closing the `?>` is treating the symptoms, not the cause. The root cause of the technical problem in this case is not fixed. Omitting the closing tag is an unintuitive solution to a technical problem achieved through an abuse of syntax.

Comment: @Micheal Ending HTML document with `</html>` is required by the documentation and won't introduce potential bug in your page. Adding the `?>` at the end is optional and can introduce potential bug. We are not talking of the same thing at all.

Comment: PHP is not a mark-up language so there is no real comparison to HTML. And an HTML document can be correctly formed without certain closing tags, eg <hr> and <br>... XHTML would be a different matter

Comment: I understand your guys' side of the argument and I appreciate the examples and the link to Zend's website. I'm going to leave this argument at that because I believe it can strongly be argued either way. When it comes down to it, it's really up to the coder. I learned something new here today and I retract my original statement about never closing PHP tags. Personally, I'll continue to close them because that feels right by me. You all have your reasons and preferences for doing your own thing and that's what's great about the flexibility of this language.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a [BOM character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check your templates if you are using them... the problem could be there and not in your main code.

and yes is a GOOD PRACTICE in PHP not to close the ending tag.

Comment: Hey dont believe me....

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

There really is no good way to go about debugging this.  You need to go through every file the page is hitting and figure out where the output is coming from.  If you really wanted to be lazy about it you could do some output buffering, but this isn't the right way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this can be difficult to track down. If you're in some kind of framework or system that includes a lot of files, you might try a `var_dump(get_included_files())` on the line before your error occurs, and that will give you a place to start. If that isn't sufficient, xdebug might get you further. Things to look out for are space before and after the PHP tags, and functions that might send output.